# Deploy SSIS Package without including .dtsx extension

Tags: sql, ssis

I am trying to deploy SSIS package under SQL Server 2017.
When i deploy package ABC.dtsx, it include .dtsx in package name after deployment. ie. ABC.dtsx

Can i avoid .dtsx extension at destination server?

Thanks,
PK.

Comment: An SSIS package IS a .dtsx file. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't want the .dtsx in the SSIS package deploy.  I guess, depending on how you deploy the package you could strip out the file extension, but then I'm not sure that SQL Server would be able to detect the package and execute it appropriately.

Comment: Deploying to where: msdb, SSISDB or filesystem? Deploying how - windows copy, dtutil or ssisdeploymentwizard?